# EF Core 7 - Mock Views

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using SQLite and `EntityFrameworkCore.Testing.Moq` to create test databases for integration tests. The `DbContextFactory` implementation buffers the connection and creates clean `DbContext` instances every time:

```
connection ??= new SqliteConnection("Data Source=Database;Mode=Memory");
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TDbContext>()
    .UseSqlite(connection, _ => { });

var dbContextToMock = (Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TDbContext), builder.Options) as TDbContext)!;
dbContextToMock.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    await dbContextToMock.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
    await dbContextToMock.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
}

var mockedDbContext = new MockedDbContextBuilder<TDbContext>().UseDbContext(dbContextToMock).MockedDbContext;
var moqMockedDbContext = Mock.Get(mockedDbContext);

// Since EF 7 the Property Model in mockedDbContext is null. Set manually
moqMockedDbContext.SetupGet(c => c.Model).Returns(dbContextToMock.Model);
```

This allows clean `DbContext` instances while keeping the data when creating a new one. But you cannot insert view data since `AddRange` does not work on views. So I allowed adding view data on the factory level that is added through mocking every time a new instance is created.

```
var dbContextType = typeof(TDbContext);

foreach (var viewData in ViewData)
{
    var entityType = viewData.Key;
    var dbSetType = typeof(DbSet<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
    var dbSetPropertyInfo = dbContextType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType == dbSetType);

    if (dbSetPropertyInfo is null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDbContext));
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, dbSetPropertyInfo);
    var lambdaFunctionType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TDbContext), dbSetType);
    var lambdaPropertyExpression = Expression.Lambda(lambdaFunctionType, propertyExpression, parameterExpression);

    var setup = mockedDbContext.GetType()
        .GetMethods().First(mi => mi.Name == nameof(mockedDbContext.Setup) && mi.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
        .MakeGenericMethod(dbSetType)
        .Invoke(mockedDbContext, new object?[] { lambdaPropertyExpression });

    typeof(MoqExtensions)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .First(mi => mi.Name == nameof(MoqExtensions.ReturnsDbSet) && mi.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2)
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TDbContext), entityType)
        .Invoke(null, new object?[] { setup, viewData.Value, null });
}
```

This calls extension methods for Moq to return a `DbSet`. This internally just forwards the `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` implementation of the `DbSet` to the implementation of a list. This worked fine when querying only the view.

But now I am faced with the problem that I have to join the view data with table data in a more complex query. This fails with the error that I use more than one `DbContext` instance so it seems that the different `IQueryable` implementation is recognized as a different context.

So I need a different approach to mock view data. I can't put the whole query into another view because I need various input values. Also, I can't buffer the view data before executing the rest of the query because the view is used in a nested query and EF Core will not be able to translate it.